# Install CoreOS on HP thin client

Tags: thin-client, coreos

I am trying to install CoreOS on HP Thin Client, but I am unable to format the flash drive.
i have created the USB boot as per https://github.com/jriguera/coreos-usb-creator - then i can login to the thin client, but when i try to install CoreOS, i get the following error

```
khine@coreos /tmp $ sudo su
bash-4.2# coreos-install -d /dev/sda -C stable -c cloud-config.yml
Checking availability of "local-file"
Fetching user-data from datasource of type "local-file"
Downloading the signature for http://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/766.3.0/coreos_production_image.bin.bz2...
2015-09-21 15:49:14 URL:http://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/766.3.0/coreos_production_image.bin.bz2.sig [543/543] -> "/tmp/coreos-install.kGAdApmypF/coreos_production_image.bin.bz2.sig" [1]
Downloading, writing and verifying coreos_production_image.bin.bz2...

bunzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
bunzip2: No space left on device
    Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)
Cannot write to '-' (Broken pipe).
gpg: Signature made Wed Sep  2 04:32:09 2015 UTC using RSA key ID E5676EFC
gpg: key 93D2DCB4 marked as ultimately trusted
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
gpg: BAD signature from "CoreOS Buildbot (Offical Builds) <buildbot@coreos.com>" [ultimate]
1: Download of coreos_production_image.bin.bz2 did not complete
141: Cannot expand coreos_production_image.bin.bz2 to /dev/sda
1: GPG signature verification failed for coreos_production_image.bin.bz2
/dev/sda: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (PMBR): 55 aa
/dev/sda: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
bash-4.2#
```

If i try to mount the drive, I get the following:

```
bash-4.2# mount /dev/sda /mnt
mount: /dev/sda is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

the flash drive is 500Mb - any advise on how i can install coreOS on HP thin client t5720?

Comment: `bunzip2: No space left on device` - the downloaded bz2 file extracts to a 4.42Gb image. It's not going to fit on a 500Mb flash drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your question:

> the flash drive is 500Mb

while the error is

> ```
> bunzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
> bunzip2: No space left on device
> ```

and your downloaded file http://stable.release.core-os.net/amd64-usr/766.3.0/coreos_production_image.bin.bz2 is 186 MB in compressed data and expanding to a 4,756,340,736 byte (4.5 GB) file.

Given that the largest available flash module for the t5720 is 1 GB (AH430AA according to the model's [QuickSpecs](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetPDF.aspx%2Fc04142026.pdf)), you only have the option of cracking the device open to see if the "flash module" is simply a USB storage stick or a PATA flash module. If it is, replacement with industry-standard parts should be smooth.

Comment: Keep in mind that CoreOS keeps two copies of the same `usr` partition so that it can pivot between them for updates.  In addition there is a root disk as well.  For a smaller version of this try the ISO image which does not have these partitions.  In that case you can just dd the image onto the drive.